# Entity framework and Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to learn Entity framework. Say, I have the following classes

```
class Course
{
  [Key]
  public virtual int CourseID {get; set;}
  public virtual string CourseName {get; set;}
}
class CourseDBContext:DBContext
{
   public DbSet<Course> Courses{get;set;}
}
```

Then I can use Linq to query the database as shown below

```
using (CourseDBContext a = new CourseDBContext())
{
  var b = from c in a.Course
          where c.CourseID == 1001
          select c;

  var d = b.FirstOrDefault();
  if(d != null)
    Console.WriteLine(d.CourseName);
}
```

This works fine. Now if I add a second class

```
class Assignment
{
   [Key]
   public virtual int CourseID {get; set;}
   public virtual int StaffID {get; set;}
}
class AssignmentDBContext:DBContext
{
   public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments{get;set;}
}
```

Now, How can I use Linq to select and display the CourseName and StaffID associated with CourseID = 1001? 
The example above is contrived and so the table design and fields are irrelevant. I just want to know how to query the data between two classes from two different database tables using Entity Framework and Linq.

Thanks

Comment: It is also a good idea to get used to using `IDbSet` instead of `DbSet`.  EF will continue to work the same, but it makes your code more testable later on, because you can mock the IDbSet in a context. I've never understood why all Microsoft's examples use DbSet instead of IDbSet...

Comment: @rally25rs Thanks. I will look into using IDbSet

Comment: If it helps, I also have a fake `iDbSet` implementation that uses a `List` to simulate a DB for unit testing, on Gist: https://gist.github.com/1492134 I use that code a lot in my MVC projects. I make my DbContext an interface too, then use those fake IDbSets in the mocked context.

Comment: You only have to declare your relationship variables as virtual. So you don't need virtual on CourseId or CourseName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both entities need to be in the same context.

```
public class CoursesContext: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments {get; set;}    
   public DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}
```

You can add an Assignment navigation property to filter on a foreign key:

```
public class Course
{
  [Key]
  public virtual int CourseID {get; set;}
  public virtual string CourseName {get; set;}
  public virtual Assignment {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can query like so:

```
var staffId = 
      from c in a.Course
      where c.CourseID == 1001
      select c.Assignment.StaffID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a seperate context for each DbSet. I.e

```
class MyDbContext : DBContext
{
   public DbSet<Course> Courses{get;set;}
   public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments{get;set;}
}
```